# Reduction formula for $I_{n, k} = \int x^k \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n \ \mathrm d x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, reduction-formula

I am studying the *Oxford Concise Dictionary of Mathematics* by Richard Earl and James Nicholson, 6th Edition (2021). There are some new results in Appendix 8: Integrals which were added since the 5th edition. At least two of these are demonstrably wrong, and this next one I've been trying to resolve that I think may also be wrong:

For the integral
$$I_{n, k} = \int x^k \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n \ \mathrm d x$$
with $n \ge 0$, $k \ge 2$, show the reduction formula
$$I_{n, k} = \dfrac {x^{k-1} \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^{n + 1} }{\left({k + 2 n + 1}\right)} - \dfrac {B \left({k - 1}\right)} {\left({k + 2 n + 1}\right)} I_{n, k-2} - \dfrac {A \left({k + n}\right)} {\left({k + 2 n + 1}\right)} I_{n, k-1}$$

My approach is to use integration by parts, using $\int u \ \mathrm d v = u v - \int v \ \mathrm d u$ where $u = \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n$ and $\mathrm d v = x^k$, but from the form of the solution it appears as though it begs for $u$ and $\mathrm d v$ to be the other way round (as in the $u v$ part the power of $u$ has decreased and the power of $v$ has increased).
But using $\mathrm d v = \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n$ gives a difficult integration to find $v$ which is almost as troublesome as this beast we're trying to solve.
Hence I tried $u = \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n$ and $\mathrm d v = x^k$, which are more manageable.
This gives $\mathrm d u = n \left({2 x + A}\right) \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^{n - 1}$ and $v = \frac {x^{k + 1} } {k + 1}$.
Flogging through the algebra gets us to:

$$I_{n, k} = \dfrac {x^{k + 1} \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n} {k + 1} - \dfrac {2 n} {k + 1} I_{n - 1, k + 2} - \dfrac {A n} {k + 1} I_{n - 1, k + 1}$$

which is a good start, and we can get to the required powers in the fraction by using the above to evaluate instead:

$$I_{n + 1, k - 2} = \dfrac {x^{k - 1} \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^{n + 1} } {k - 1} - \dfrac {2 \left({n + 1}\right) } {k - 1} I_{n, k} - \dfrac {A \left({n + 1}\right) } {k - 1} I_{n, k - 1}$$

Rearranging this, we get:

$$I_{n, k} = \dfrac {x^{k - 1} \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^{n + 1} } {2 n + 2} - \dfrac {k - 1} {2 n + 2} I_{n + 1, k - 2} - \dfrac {A \left({n + 1}\right) } {2 n + 2} I_{n, k - 1}$$

Close, but nowhere near a cigar.

Anyone able to offer a hint as to how to proceed, or what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x)=x^2+Ax+B$ and differentiate

\begin{align}
& \frac d{dx}\left[x^{k-1}h^{n+1}(x)\right]\\
= &\left[ (k+2n+1)x^k +A(k+n)x^{k-1}+B(k-1) x^{k-2}\right]h^n(x)
\end{align}

Integrate both sides and then rearrange to obtain the sought-after reduction formula

\begin{align}
I_{n, k} =&\int x^k (x^2+Ax+B )^n dx \\
=& \ \frac1{k+2n+1}\left[ x^{k-1} h^{n + 1} (x) - {A \left({k + n}\right)} I_{n, k-1}- {B \left({k - 1}\right)} I_{n, k-2}\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this - apologies it took so long to acknowledge it, I've just now noticed it!

Answer (score 0):

*Let us check if this is correct.*

Writing for simplicity
$$x^2+Ax+B=(x-a)(x-b)$$ the result is
$$I_{n,k}=\frac {a^n\,b^n}{k+1}\,x^{k+1}\,\,F_1\left(k+1;-n,-n;k+2;\frac{x}{a},\frac{x}{b}\right)$$

where appears  the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

If $b=a$, it  reduces to
$$I_{n,k}=\frac {a^{2n}}{k+1}\,x^{k+1}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(k+1,-2 n;k+2;\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

**I am just stupid and I stop here!**

Look atformula $2.171.1$  in the *"Table of Integrals, Series and Products"* (seventh edition) by *I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik*.

Adapted to your formulation , it just gives the result from the book.

Comment: I am going to have to research this, as it is outside of my area of knowledge. I have cracked open chapter 15 of Abramowitz and Stegun, which is a fairly comprehensive and dense presentation of the Hypergeometric Functions, but this needs studying.