# Reduction formula for $I_n (a, b) := \int \frac {a x + b} {(x^2 + A x + B)^n} \mathrm d x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, reduction-formula

Context: *Oxford Concise Dictionary of Mathematics* by Richard Earl and James Nicholson, 6th Edition (2021).

Self-study as a hobbyist.

We are given:

For $I_n (a, b) := \displaystyle \int \dfrac {a x + b} {(x^2 + A x + B)^n} \mathrm d x$ where $n \ge 2$, then:

$$I_n (a, b) = \dfrac {b A - 2 a B + (2 b - a A) x} {(n - 1) (4 B - A^2) (x^2 + A x + B)^n} + \dfrac {(2 n - 3) (2 b - a A)} {(n - 1) (4 B - A^2)} I_{n - 1} (0, 1)$$

My mission is to try to prove this.

I have used a similar technique to that used on this question:

[Reduction formula for $I_{n, k} = \int x^k \left({x^2 + A x + B}\right)^n \ \mathrm d x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687851/reduction-formula-for-i-n-k-int-xk-leftx2-a-x-b-rightn-mat)

as follows.

Let $h$ be the real function defined as:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: h (x) = x^2 + A x + B$$

Thus we have:
$$I_n (a, b) := \int \dfrac {a x + b} {(h (x))^n} \mathrm d x$$

Then, in order to get the suggestive coefficients in the answer given above, we do:

$$\dfrac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm d x} \left({\dfrac {a x + b} {(h (x))^{n - 1} } }\right) = (a x + b) \dfrac {-(n - 1)} {(h (x))^n} (2 x + A) + \dfrac a {(h (x))^{n - 1} }$$

using the product rule, chain rule and power rules for diffing.

After considerable algebra, we reach:

$$\dfrac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm d x} \left({\dfrac {a x + b} {(h (x))^{n - 1} } }\right) = -(n - 1) \dfrac {b A - 2 a B + (2 b - a A) x} {(h (x))^n} + \dfrac {a (3 - 2 n)} {(h (x))^{n - 1} }$$

The idea is then that we integrate both sides wrt $x$ to get:

$$\dfrac {a x + b} {(h (x))^{n - 1} } + a (2 n - 3) \int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {(h (x))^{n - 1} } = -(n - 1) \int \dfrac {b A - 2 a B + (2 b - a A) x} {(h (x))^n} \mathrm d x$$

Expressing in terms of $I_n$ this is:

$$\dfrac {a x + b} {(x^2 + A x + B)^{n - 1} } + a (2 n - 3) I_{n - 1} (0, 1) = -(n - 1) (b A - 2 a B + (2 b - a A)) I_n (1, 0)$$

which is nowhere near where we are aiming.

We note that we have that required $I_{n - 1} (0, 1)$, and the coefficients $(n - 1$ and $(2 n - 3)$ in ''almost'' the right places, but even after we bend and strain the result by piling on the algebra to force $I_n (a, b)$ to appear, the fact remains that can't seem to get the term $\displaystyle \int \dfrac {a x + b} {(h (n))^n} \mathrm d x$ without leaving a term in $\displaystyle \int \dfrac Q {(h (n))^n} \mathrm d x$ where $Q$ is messy.

Nothing else I've tried comes remotely close to anything even approaching the expected coefficients, and nothing seems to allow me to eliminate spurious terms of $I_n$ and/or $I_{n - 1}$.

Anyone have any ideas as to what my approach might need to be?

Comment: It might help to write $ax+b=\frac12 a (2x+A)+(b-\frac12 a A)$. Then $I_n$ splits into two pieces: the first is easy to integrate and the second could be attacked as you have done above.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Your comment would probably work as an answer.

Comment: Integrals of the form $\int \frac{x^k}{\left(A x+B+x^2\right)^n} \, dx$ can be obtained by differentiating this function $\int \frac{\exp (t x)}{A x+B+x^2} \, dx=\frac{e^{-A t} \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{A^2-4 B}+A\right)} \text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2} t \left(A+2 x-\sqrt{A^2-4 B}\right)\right)-e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(A-\sqrt{A^2-4 B}\right)} \text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2} t \left(A+2 x+\sqrt{A^2-4 B}\right)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{A^2-4 B}}$ with respect to $B$ and $t$, respectively

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze With all due respect, that's one of the most horrendously complicated integrations I've ever seen. This (however it is arrived at) would not be my go-to method for solving this. Do you have a reference for where I can find this?

Comment: @ Prime Mover The integral is not complicated. Notice that the denominator can be written as (x-a)(x-b), and after partial fraction decomposition we are left with integrals of this type: $\int \frac{e^{t x}}{x-a} \, dx$ which can be expressed as $e^{a t} \text{Ei}(-a t+t x)$. Using these ingredients you will easily verify the expression I gave in the first comment.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze yes it is, it's ridiculously complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $h(x)=x^2+Ax+B$ and $K_n=\int \frac1{h(x)^n}dx$, establish
$$\left(\frac{2x+A}{h(x)^{n-1}} \right)’= \frac{2(3-2n)}{h(x)^{n-1}}+\frac{(n-1)(4B-A^2)}{h(x)^{n}}
$$
and, in turn
$$\frac{2x+A}{h(x)^{n-1}}= 2(3-2n)K_{n-1}+(n-1)(4B-A^2)K_n\tag1
$$
Note that

\begin{align}
I_n (a, b) &= \int \dfrac {a x + b} {(x^2 + A x + B)^n} d x\\
&= \frac a2\int \dfrac {2 x + A} {h(x)^n} d x
 + \frac {2 b -aA}2\int \frac {1} {h(x)^n} d x\\
&= -\frac a{2(n-1)h(x)^{n-1}}+  \frac {2 b -aA}2K_n
\end{align}
Utilize (1) to replace $K_n$, along with $K_{n-1}=I_{n-1}(0,1)$

$$I_n (a, b) = \dfrac {b A - 2 a B + (2 b - a A) x} {(n - 1) (4 B - A^2) h(x)^{n-1}} + \dfrac {(2 n - 3) (2 b - a A)} {(n - 1) (4 B - A^2)} I_{n - 1} (0, 1)$$